# assign a variable to JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

Consider I have a value which i have to set as day in `JodaTime`.

```
int new_day;
```

this is my day which I have to set as day in `JodaTime`. I already have a time in `JodaTime` object which is `2014-04-01T10:10:10.000+05:30`.
i want to set the date 01 to 15 and  consider value of `new_day = 15;`. 
I want this 15 instead of 01 and the answer should be coming like this after changing.
`2014-04-15T10:10:10.000+05:30`.
This is what i tried and not working

```
start=start.plusDays(new_day);
```

Thanks

Comment: "and not working" doesn't give nearly enough information. I'd expect that to give a value of the 16th of April given that you're adding 15 days... but you should clarify your question to confirm that. Also, please tell us which *type* you're using in Joda Time. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: (Your title is also hopelessly vague. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and follow the guidance there to ask better questions in the future.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `start` variable is of time `DateTime`, I suspect you want [`DateTime.withDayOfMonth`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withDayOfMonth%28int%29):

```
start = start.withDayOfMonth(new_day);
```

Other types (e.g. `LocalDateTime`) have similar methods.

(I'd also advise you to start following Java naming conventions, using camelCasing instead of underscore_separation.)

Comment: @sarath: No, you shouldn't just tack on extra (and incomplete!) questions as comments on a different question. Ask a new question, but ask a *good* one this time. Read the hints I linked to earlier.